# UIButton's method setTitle does not (always) set a title to my button

Tags: ios, swift, function, uibutton

I'm trying to program a simple Memory Game (with animals' name) to practice with Swift.
I actually successfully did it except for one thing that is really strange to me:
in a memory you select two buttons, their content is shown, and if they are equal they remain uncovered, otherwise they go back in their covered mode.

Here's the puzzle:
when I select two buttons with the same animal, they indeed show their content, but when the second one is different with respect to the first one, only the first one is shown and the second is not.
But the function that is called to show the content is the same, in the code below it's `turn_button(...)`.
I'm about to paste all the viewController.swift code, but here are the 3 lines that do not work (setTitle to buttons or label):

```
    pressed_start.setTitle("You Can Play!)", forState:UIControlState.Normal)

    default: //cioè prima casella selezionata
        if animals_alive[sender.tag-1] == 1 && couple_set_index[0] != sender.tag
        { //cioè se non tra i già morti e non è stato premuto in caso 0
            couple_set[1] = animals_index[sender.tag-1] ; couple_set_index[1] = sender.tag
            print(animals_in_table[couple_set_index[1]-1])
            turn_button(couple_set_index[1], withwhat: animals_in_table[couple_set_index[1]-1]) //Non lo esegue! esegue però i due Print prima e dopo!!!

    pressed_start.setTitle("Play Again!)", forState:UIControlState.Normal)
```

Here the whole code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var animals: [String] = ["Dog", "Cat", "Cow", "Mouse", "Horse", "Chicken", "Sheep", "Pig"]
var animals_index = [Int](count: 16, repeatedValue: 0)
var animals_in_table: [String]=[]
var animals_alive = [Int](count:16, repeatedValue: 1)
var position = 0
var startGame_sent = 0
var couple_set = [0,0] //Qui serve che quando ne ha scelto 1 si possano scegliere solo gli altri e quando ne ha scelti 2 dopo 2 secondi o si azzerino le caselle o si eliminino le due scelte se uguali (e qui l'eliminazione e riapparizione per il gioco dopo non è banale!)
var couple_set_index = [0 , 0]

@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_8: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_9: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_10: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_11: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_12: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_13: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_14: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_15: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var assign_animal_to_button_16: UIButton!

func turn_button(which_one: Int, withwhat: String) {
    switch which_one {
    case 1: assign_animal_to_button_1.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 2: assign_animal_to_button_2.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 3: assign_animal_to_button_3.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 4: assign_animal_to_button_4.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 5: assign_animal_to_button_5.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 6: assign_animal_to_button_6.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 7: assign_animal_to_button_7.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 8: assign_animal_to_button_8.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 9: assign_animal_to_button_9.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 10: assign_animal_to_button_10.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 11: assign_animal_to_button_11.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 12: assign_animal_to_button_12.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 13: assign_animal_to_button_13.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 14: assign_animal_to_button_14.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 15: assign_animal_to_button_15.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    case 16: assign_animal_to_button_16.setTitle(withwhat, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    default: break
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var pressed_start: UIButton!

@IBAction func startGame(sender: UIButton) {
    startGame_sent = 1 // non esegue le due istruzioni sotto, perchè col tasto 1 va invece? per adesso imposto = 1 all'inizio
    pressed_start.setTitle("You Can Play!)", forState:UIControlState.Normal)


    var animals_ints = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8] //Indici degli animali da distribuire
    let start_button_random = Int(arc4random_uniform(15)) ; print("start_button_random: \(start_button_random)")
    position = start_button_random + 1 // così va da 1 a 16
    repeat {
        if animals_alive[position-1] == 1 {
            animals_index[position-1] = animals_ints.removeLast()
            animals_alive[position-1] = 0
        }
        let step = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(animals_ints.count)+1))
        print("Step: \(step)")
        if position + step < 17 {position = position + step} else {position = position + step - 16}
        print("Animals_index: \(animals_index)")
        print("Animals_alive: \(animals_alive)")
        print("position: \(position)")
    } while animals_alive.contains(1) == true
    animals_alive = [Int](count:16, repeatedValue: 1)

    animals_in_table = [] //Azzerare per il secondo gioco
    for index_table in 0...15 {
    animals_in_table.append(animals[animals_index[index_table]-1])
    print(animals_in_table)
    }
startGame_sent = 1 // Prima di ricominciare, ma perchè c'è anche sopra???
}

@IBAction func pressed_button(sender: UIButton) {  // Va in crash se clicco su Bottone prima di Start...
    if startGame_sent == 1 {
    let stato_del_gioco = couple_set[0] + couple_set[1]
    switch stato_del_gioco
    {case 0: //Nessuna casella selezionata --> Problema se scegli per primo casella 1 perchè lui la vede come 0 e dopo nn va avanti al Caso 1
        if animals_alive[sender.tag-1] == 1 { //cioè se non tra i già morti
            couple_set[0] = animals_index[sender.tag-1] ; couple_set_index[0] = sender.tag
            turn_button(couple_set_index[0], withwhat: animals_in_table[couple_set_index[0]-1])
            print("Caso 0 - Casella \(sender.tag) - Animale \(animals_in_table[sender.tag-1) - Coppia scelta: \(couple_set) e Coppia Scelta Index: \(couple_set_index)")
        }
    default: //cioè prima casella selezionata
        if animals_alive[sender.tag-1] == 1 && couple_set_index[0] != sender.tag
        { //cioè se non tra i già morti e non è stato premuto in caso 0
            couple_set[1] = animals_index[sender.tag-1] ; couple_set_index[1] = sender.tag
            print(animals_in_table[couple_set_index[1]-1])
            turn_button(couple_set_index[1], withwhat: animals_in_table[couple_set_index[1]-1]) //Non lo esegue! esegue però i due Print prima e dopo!!!
            print("Caso 1 - Casella \(String(couple_set_index[1])) - Animale \(animals_in_table[couple_set_index[1]-1) - Coppia scelta: \(couple_set) e Coppia Scelta Index: \(couple_set_index)")
        }
    }
    if couple_set_index[1] > 0 {turn_button(couple_set_index[1], withwhat: animals_in_table[couple_set_index[1]-1])} //Non so perchè ma pare lo esegua solo al giro dopo...
    if couple_set_index[1] > 0 {//Ovvero solo se anche la seconda casella è selezionata
        if couple_set[0] == couple_set[1] { //Ci hai preso! Animali uguali diventano "dead" in animals_alive
            print("Sono uguali: Coppia Scelta = \(couple_set) - Etichetta sul pulsante premuto = \(sender.tag)")
            animals_alive[couple_set_index[0]-1]=0 ; animals_alive[couple_set_index[1]-1]=0
        }
        else { //Sono diversi, la funzione initialize_buttons li ricoprirà lasciandoli vivi adesso in "animals_alive"
            print("Sono diversi: Coppia Scelta = \(couple_set) e Coppia Scelta Index: \(couple_set_index) - Etichetta sul pulsante premuto = \(String(couple_set_index[1]))")
        }
        }
    if couple_set_index[1] > 0
    { //Ovvero solo se anche la seconda casella è selezionata
        turn_button(couple_set_index[1], withwhat: animals_in_table[couple_set_index[1]-1]) // Non va neanche qui!!!
        initialize_buttons(animals_alive)
    }
    }
    for index in 0...15 {
        if  couple_set_index[1]-1 == index {turn_button(index+1, withwhat: animals_in_table[index])} // Provo qui a scoprire gli animali del caso 1! non va!!!!!!!
    }
}

func initialize_buttons(animals_alive_arg: Array<Int>) {
    print(animals_alive)
//    sleep(1)
    for index in 0...15 {
        if animals_alive_arg[index] == 1 {turn_button(index+1, withwhat: String(index+1))}
    }
    couple_set = [0,0]; couple_set_index = [0,0]
    if animals_alive_arg.contains(1) == false {
        pressed_start.setTitle("Play Again!)", forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        startGame_sent = 0
        animals_alive = [Int](count:16, repeatedValue: 1)
        initialize_buttons(animals_alive)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That code is almost unreadable. What is `couple_set_index`? what is `couple_set`? What is stored in `button.tag`?

Comment: Really sorry for my mess, that's my first try:

Comment: Couple_set represents the two buttons of choice for a hand of the game (a classic "memory"), couple_set_index the same thing but the first contains a Number representing a unique animal, and the second its place in the table of buttons. The tag is the Number of the button. This helps?